# Convert byte to BitmapImage uwp c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, byte

I try to convert a white bitmapImage to black. So i have a byte[] PixelArray, which is good but when i try to use this array to create my black image it doesn't work. Here is my code :

```
var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer());
stream.Seek(0);
await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
```

Thanks guys

Comment: `BitmapImage.SetSourceAsync` does not accept a raw pixel buffer, but only an encoded bitmap frame, e.g. a PNG or JPEG. You may use a WriteableBitmap instead.

Comment: How do you get the bytes Array? If you get it from, we should be able to get it by you method.

Comment: Hi Jayden Gu, thanks for your comment. This is how i get my array :

Comment: IRandomAccessStream random = await RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(ImageWhite.UriSource).OpenReadAsync();
                BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random);
                PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();

                PixelArray = pixelData.DetachPixelData();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Clemens said, we should be able to use [`WriteableBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx). We can get the Width and the Height by [`BitmapDecoder.PixelWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.pixelwidth.aspx) and [`BitmapDecoder.PixelHeight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.pixelheight.aspx) property. Then we can use [`WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer.aspx) to set the bytes Array to the `WriteableBitmap`.

> PixelBuffer cannot be written to directly, however, you can use language-specific techniques to access the buffer and change its contents.
>   To access the pixel content from C# or Microsoft Visual Basic, you can use the AsStream extension method to access the underlying buffer as a stream.

For more info, see Remarks of the [`WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer.aspx).

For example:

```
IRandomAccessStream random = await RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(ImageWhite.UriSour‌​ce).OpenReadAsync();
BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random);
PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
var PixelArray = pixelData.DetachPixelData();
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
await bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream().WriteAsync(PixelArray, 0, PixelArray.Length);
MyImage.Source = bitmap;
```

Update:

To Convert the `WriteableBitmap` to `BitmapImage`, we should be able to encode the stream from `WriteableBitmap`.

For example:

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream inMemoryRandomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, inMemoryRandomAccessStream);
Stream pixelStream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
byte[] pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, pixels);
await encoder.FlushAsync();
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.SetSource(inMemoryRandomAccessStream);
MyImage.Source = bitmapImage;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But MyImage is a bitmapImage and i don'i know how to convert writeableBitmap to bitmapimage. Do you know how ?

Comment: As @Clemens said, BitmapImage.SetSourceAsync does not accept a raw pixel buffer, but only an encoded bitmap frame, e.g. a PNG or JPEG. Also why do you want to get the `BitmapImage`? It seems we can set the WriteableBitmap to the Image.Source directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My imageSource is a btimapImage, my application does somes other stuff with it and i need to convert my bitmap to a bitmapImage

Comment: I have update the answer about how to convert writeableBitmap to bitmapimage.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)