# Why Task.Run not processing all lines on Task?

Tags: c#, uwp, task

Im using WebApi to Deserialize Object on client side, witch contains some lightweight images, the code reads:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, object e)
    {
        LoadApi();
    }

    private async void LoadApi()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync("http://" + 
            TxtIP.Text + "/api/prod");

            if (responseMessage.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                List<ClsProd> lstData = new List<ClsProd>();
                var jsonResponse = await 
                responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (jsonResponse != null)
                {
                    lstData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClsProd>>(jsonResponse);
                }                        
                ListView1.ItemsSource = lstData;
            }
        }
    }
```

my ClsProd looks witch get all data from Web Api is:

```
public class ClsProd : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public int IAuto { get; set; }
    public int IDevc { get; set; }
    public string SName { get; set; }
    public string SImax { get; set; }
    public ImageSource ImgPg { get; set; }

    public ClsProd(int auto, int devc, string name, string imax)
    {
        IAuto = auto;
        IDevc = devc;
        SName = name;
        SImax = imax;


        ClsImgBase64 CImg = new ClsImgBase64();
        CImg.EvtResult += CImg_EvtResult;
        CImg.Start(imax);
    }

    private void CImg_EvtResult(ImageSource e)
    {
        ImgPg = e;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ImgPg");
    }
}
```

All data is properly fetch and displayed on list, including `string SImax` witch is image encoded as Base64 string. The only problem is image conversion from base64 string to image is not happening.

Here is my class it does not pass the 1st statment on Task.Run, please help me find what is wrong. Also same funcition works when called from async void.

```
        public class ClsImgBase64
        {
                public event Action<ImageSource> EvtResult;
              
                public ClsImgBase64()
                {
    
                }
    
                public void Start(string s)
                {
                    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => 
                    {
                        //read stream
                        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
    
                        var image = bytes.AsBuffer().AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream();
                        //decode image
                        //var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(image);
                        image.Seek(0);
                        //create bitmap
                        var output = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
                        await output.SetSourceAsync(image);
    
                        if (EvtResult != null)
                        {
                            EvtResult(output);
                        }
                    });
                }
         }
```

Comment: `it does not pass the 1st statment on Task.Run` how did you find that? Why do you need a separate thread for already `async` code? What are you trying to solve? Please update the question with debugging details.

Comment: Guessing that `uwp` and `android` tags are conflicting because UWP is something about Windows not Android.

Comment: I found by debuging all lines that it does not pass statment  byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s);

Comment: About android...yes it may not be proper, but im working on Uno Project, so it may apply also there.

Comment: Don't add comments, fix the post instead with as much details as possible. Also ensure that you're debugging it without `optimize code` option set that located in Project Build Properties.

Comment: `async void LoadApi()` to fix the code i need a code of a caller method. Some event handler? Include it. Because `async void` is can be avoided.

Comment: Fixed that..sorry was typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `async void` there's probably an Exception thrown which was lost and not displayed bacause the executing code is not awaited. Let's fix it.

#### Web part

- avoid `async void` in methods that's aren't event handlers, also handle all possible exceptions in `async void` method
- `HttpClient` is intended to be instantiated once per app rather than per use
- `HttpResponseMessage` is `IDisposable`

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, object e)
{
    try
    {
        await LoadDataAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // show ex.Message here in UI or log it
    }
}

private static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

private async Task LoadDataAsync()
{
    using var response = await _client.GetAsync($"http://{TxtIP.Text}/api/prod");
    string json = await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    List<ClsProd> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClsProd>>(json);
    ListView1.ItemsSource = data;
    await DecodeAllImagesAsync(data);
}

// decoding all at once asynchronously, see implementation below
private Task DecodeAllImagesAsync(List<ClsProd> data)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(data.Select(item => item.DecodeImageAsync()).ToArray());
}
```

[Consider using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview) `System.Text.Json` to deserealize instead of old `Newtonsoft.Json`. It would allow to deserealize `response.Content` as `Stream`, faster with less memory consumption e.g:

```cs
using var stream = await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
List<ClsProd> data = await JsonSerializer.DeserealizeAsync<List<ClsProd>>(stream);
```

#### Data part

Use `using` directives at the beggining of the code to attach namespaces that will help not to repeat namespaces in the code explicitly

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
```

It makes possible to write `INotifyPropertyChanged` instead of `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged`. I'll remove inlined namespaces below.

- don't start long-running job from a constructor, it's unpredictable behavior because costructor must be always successful. Start loading images later. Also constructor cannot await asynchronous tasks. Separate method can.

```cs
public class ClsProd : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ImageSource _imgPg;

    public int IAuto { get; set; }
    public int IDevc { get; set; }
    public string SName { get; set; }
    public string SImax { get; set; }
    public ImageSource ImgPg
    {
        get => _imgPg;
        set
        {
            _imgPg = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ClsProd(int auto, int devc, string name, string imax)
    {
        IAuto = auto;
        IDevc = devc;
        SName = name;
        SImax = imax;
    }

    public async Task DecodeImageAsync()
    {
        ImgPg = await ClsImgBase64.DecodeAsync(SImax);
    }
}
```

#### Decoder

As now it's awaitable and doesn't need a callback, decoding method doesn't interact with the instance data. So, it can be `static`.

```cs
public static class ClsImgBase64
{
    public static async Task<ImageSource> DecodeAsync(string base64)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        using var stream = bytes.AsBuffer().AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream();
        // stream.Seek(0); // not sure if it needed
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        var pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
        var pixelArray = pixelData.DetachPixelData();
        var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
        await bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream().WriteAsync(pixelArray, 0, pixelArray.Length);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

*Decoder's code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41234284/12888024).*

If it will be laggy, try to wrap 2 Decoder's lines with `Task.Run`. Only if it will be laggy.

```
using var stream = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    return bytes.AsBuffer().AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream();
});
```

Finally: give classes, methods and other things more clear names, that would make the code maintainable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after these changes it work.